# "Parameter count mismatch" on running exe from memory

Tags: c#, exception, memory

This is my working code for running a simple self-made .Net executable from memory :

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"simple.exe",FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();
        br.Close();
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
        MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
        if (method == null) return;
        object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
        method.Invoke(o, null);
```

But this code works just for tiny .exe files not other executables like *putty* or other bigger .net files.

When i want to use another exe it says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.

For this line: `method.Invoke(o, /*here*/ null);`

**Question:** What can i do and What should i looking for ? Becuse im not much into Memory handling in c#. And i want to run bigger exe files from memory for a *programming tools project*

**Note:** My working sample was a simple c# code for printing a string on console.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Marc's answer, this the final code:

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"EverySample.exe", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();
        br.Close();
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
        MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
        if (method == null) return;
        object[] parameters = method.GetParameters().Length == 0 ? null : new object[] { new string[0] };
        method.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

Comment: Your `method` instance has information about how many parameters it needs and what their types should be. Do you _know_ the entry point? You should, because you will have to provide valid arguments. By default the entry point would be a `Main` method that probably wants some `string[] args` command line args or even environment variables.

Comment: wait... why are you passing `Assembly.CreateInstance` the name of a method? that... makes no sense? what are you trying to do? what is `o` meant to be here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entry-point is the `Main()` method or equivalent. There are multiple signatures allowed for this; you *can* have a parameterless `Main()`, but you can also have `Main(string[])`. So: you should probably check the parameters on the `method` (`GetParameters()`), and pass in something - presumably an empty `string[]`.

Note that entry-points are generally `static`; there is no need to pass in an `o`, and your existing `CreateInstance` code is non-sensical (it passes a method name to something that expects a type name). You can just pass `null` as the first parameter.